# Creating Trigger with a concatenated string with a date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to figure out how to create a trigger insert with a concatenated string including the date.

The trigger I am creating is created on a tbl_employee. Every time I insert a new employee into the table I want it to update another table called tbl_employee_audit with the following information.

| id | audit_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New employee with ID = 1221 was added on Sep 21, 2016 |

Here is my code to create the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER adding_employee
AFTER INSERT
ON tbl_employee FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO tbl_employee_audit(ID, AUDIT_DATA) 
VALUES(ID, CONCAT('New employee with ID = ', new.emp_id, ‘was added on’, DATE));
```

The problem is that I can get it to work without the date added at the end, but if I try it with the date I get an error when inserting a new record into tbl_employees.

Error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'DATE' in 'field list'

What I missing here?

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want the current date?

```
CREATE TRIGGER adding_employee AFTER INSERT
ON tbl_employee FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO tbl_employee_audit(ID, AUDIT_DATA) 
        VALUES(ID, CONCAT('New employee with ID = ', new.emp_id, ' was added on ', CURRENT_DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your date you need to Format it

> ```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, "%b %d, %Y")
> ```
>
> ```
> | DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, "%b %d, %Y") |
> | :------------------------------------- |
> | Jul 21, 2021                           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecbf16cb4df3a2396386496de0ed06db)*

```
CREATE TRIGGER adding_employee AFTER INSERT
ON tbl_employee FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO tbl_employee_audit(ID, AUDIT_DATA) 
        VALUES(ID, CONCAT('New employee with ID = ', new.emp_id, ' was added on ', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, "%b %d, %Y")));
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much for your help